# app gateway backend pool ip update fails with error "Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'"

Tags: backend, azure-keyvault, azure-application-gateway

The application gateway is configured to route to backend pools based on IP. When changing the IP for one of the backend pools, the IP changes because when I go back into it the new IP is in the field, but the app gateway does not seem to be applying the change. This operation last worked 11/15, we did upload a new cert at that time that is good till Feb 23, 2023, but when trying it again on Dec 1 we now get this error:

"code":"ApplicationGatewayKeyVaultSecretException",
"message":"Problem occured while accessing and validating KeyVault Secrets associated with Application Gateway '/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/appgw-dev'. See details below:","details":[{"code":"0","message":"Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'"}]}]

The listener associated with the backend pool is configured to use a certificate in a key vault. The user managed identity for the app gateway was initially configured with get list on secrets and certificates.

I increased the permissions to ALL permissions for everything on the vault. The vault networking config is Allow access from: Allow public access from all networks. If I chose a different key vault that does not have the access policy for the identity on the listener config page, the page complains about allow access. The listener shows the right cert in the field when picking the key vault the identity has access policy configured on. I have deleted the cert and recreated, I have deleted the access policy, and gave it ALL permissions for everything, I have deleted the listener and recreated it. All produce the same error and results. The app gateway shows 502 bad gateway browser error when trying to access the URL associated with the listener. The app gateway is Standard_V2. The health probe for the listener just returns 'No Results'. None of these changes seem to register, it is like the app gateway is operating off of cached data since Dec 1 when we made the initial IP change. I have stopped and restarted the app gateway using azureCLI commands and it makes no difference, same error and issues.

Why can't the app gateway see the certificate anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue with App Gateway is once you disassociate a certificate from a listener or backend setting, the certificate is still assigned to the App Gateway.  With a Key Vault reference, the reference will still be in the configuration even if unused.  This error can occur if any of these references are to deleted or disabled certificates in Key Vault.

Since you're using Azure CLI, I would use the following command and review the JSON for the certificates:

```
az network application-gateway show --name "appgatewayname" --resource-group "rg-name"
```

You may find there are more certificates than you actually have assigned to listeners or backend settings.  Double check that none of these are referencing either a deleted or disabled Key Vault certificate.  If there are any, remove them and try to push your update again.

Comment: I have 3 listeners and through resource explorer I see the same json as the command output. 2 of the listeners still have old publicCertData associated with them. All are associated with the keyVaultSecretId. This is how it would have been configured since 11/15 and it worked.

Comment: In resource explorer, are there any SslCertificates that aren't assigned to a listener?  Also, if a KV certificate is no longer accessible this is usually not checked until you perform another update to the App Gateway.  If a certificate is deleted or disabled in KV the App Gateway won't know this until it's updated again with a PUT.

Comment: yes 4 are not associated with a listener

Comment: Can I just delete those from resource explorer? Does app gateway need to be updated? I am not familiar with the PUT you mention

Comment: Any time you make changes in Portal or with CLI/PowerShell, this does an HTTP PUT request with a JSON object similar to what you see in the Resource Explorer.

With the resource explorer in the Portal I believe you can only view.  Using the older explorer at resources.azure.com you can edit the JSON and submit the changes using the PUT button near the top.  You can also do this with "az network application-gateway ssl-cert delete" if you're more comfortable with Azure CLI.

Comment: successfully deleted all certs that were NOT associated with listeners using az cli, resource explorer shows them removed from the json. deleted ip for back end pool and get "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'". The user-managed identity on the app gateway has access policy with ALL for key, secret, and cert permissions.

Comment: I had to create a default listener and rule and deleted ALL listeners associated with the 1 cert that was left. stopped and started app gateway and the errors went away. I reconfigured 1 listener with the cert and it now works.